# Is it possible to reduce the width of a div depending on the length of text on a line?

Tags: html, css

My client is requesting a site with paragraphs that are centered horizontally, with poems written in a narrow column. This column should change width depending on the length of the words on the line.

In effect, the artistically-written width of the letters taken up by the text should determine the width of the column, so every page looks centered. Each poem (therefore, each page) may have a different number of characters per line. Is this possible??

IE:
"Mary had a little lamb
little lamb, little lamb, 
Mary had a little lamb,
its fleece was white as snow" <- The div should be only as wide as the longest width of text in the poem (here it is the last line), and should be flexible depending on whether words are added or removed, or a different font is used.

I have tried to set this up like this with inline-flex:

```css
.one {
    background: grey;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
    <div class="one">
       <p>Here is some text for div 1 depending on the size of the div.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code: https://codepen.io/Clare12345/pen/rzRNmK

But the issue I'm having is that some of the paragraphs (ie lines in the poem) are displaying next to each other rather than one above the other. `clear:both` didn't work.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what's happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxtiuuiptstes1i/Screen%20Shot%202017-09-03%20at%2010.11.24%20AM.png?dl=0

Edit 2: The answer below was almost right. Here's the CSS code that is working: 
(The website is using WordPress, and the .centered div is inside the .entry div.)

```
.postid-85 .entry {
text-align: center; 
}
.centered {
display: inline;
}
.one {
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
}
.one p {
text-align: left; 
}
```

Sorry for all the edits. It is working now!

Comment: Maybe because you have forgotten to use <br> tags?? Or are you using one <p> tag for every line in the poem?

Comment: unclear, but is that what you look for https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MvxWEV ? (flex-flow/flex-direction was missing) Else, inline-table works fine too https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vJPYWE .... so would inline-block to do simple https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mModqe

Comment: add a picture to demonstrate what you want to achieve

Comment: can you elaborate this problem `displaying next to each other rather than one above the other. clear:both didn't work` and provide a better example

Comment: @Ikillnukes My client is going to paste content in from a Word Doc into WordPress, so it creates the <p> tags automatically on the line breaks.

Comment: @G-Cyr Flex-direction and flex-flow have not changed the layout. The lines that are short in width are still next to each other. But thanks anyway! Inline-table does the same thing.

Comment: I've added an image to show what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.one {
    background: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.centered {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Probably you will also need to set flex-direction to column on .centered .

Comment: Okay, this almost fixed it. It is working, aside from the fact that now I have an !important on the text-align: left on .one p. This will not work if my client has a centered poem. Any idea on how to get a text-align: left on a this div?

Comment: Actually, now it's fixed. I'm not sure what the difference was, but it is working. I've updated the working CSS above.